# mount folder directly to subdirectory of cifs share - RHEL 9

Tags: rhel, cifs

I have a cifs share that is currently mounted on serverA (in fstab - RHEL7) as:

```
//<servername>/SHARE/folder /cifshared cifs credentials=<path to creds file>
```

This works fine on ServerA.

I am now trying to recreate this on serverB (RHEL9, using same credentials, same mountpath, same share) BUT serverB will not let me mount directly to the *subdirectory* of the share.  I can mount the mounpoint to //servername/SHARE with no error - so I know the credentials are good.  but when I try to moutn to a subfolder of the shared folder, I get **mount error(115): Operation now in progress**

Is there some option I'm missing to be able to mount directly to a subdirectory?